# Unable To Print Value Of Variable

Tags: java, mysql, variables

it seems simple to Print value of Variable in java but i am unable to do this properly. 
i have Mysql table that contains first names "fname" & last names "lname". after connecting to my sql i fetch these values and store in variables. then problem starts... here is [image: screenshot] and here is my code

```
package signup;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Random;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;

public class Signup {
private static final String db_connect = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test1" ;
private static final String uname = "username" ;
private static final String pass = "password" ;

private Connection conMethod(){
Connection conVar = null;
try{Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");conVar = DriverManager.getConnection(db_connect,uname,pass);}catch(SQLException e){e.printStackTrace();
}catch(ClassNotFoundException e){e.printStackTrace();}return conVar;}

public void selectMethod(){Statement query = null;
ResultSet rs1 = null;
Connection conVar2= conMethod();try{query = conVar2.createStatement();

rs1 = query.executeQuery("Select * from fnames2");
String[] fname=new String[500]; String[] lname=new String[500]; 
int a=0;while(rs1.next()){fname[a]=rs1.getString(2); lname[a]=rs1.getString(3); a++;}

String firstname = fname[1];
String lastname = lname[1];
String fullname = firstname+" "+lastname; 
String email = firstname+lastname+"@yahoo.com";  


System.out.println("first name is "+firstname);
System.out.println("last name is "+lastname);
System.out.println("full name is "+fullname); 
System.out.println("email is "+email); 


} catch(SQLException e){e.printStackTrace();}

}   

public static void main (String args[]){Signup obj = new Signup();obj.selectMethod();}
}
```

and here is its out put

```
first name is PATRICIA
last name is ALISHA
full name is PATRICIA ALISHA
@yahoo.comATRICIAALISHA
```

you can see problem is in email variable. it should print PATRICIAALISHA@yahoo.com but it is printing something "@yahoo.comATRICIAALISHA" . Thanks

Comment: it should print "email is PATRICIAALISHA@yahoo.com" , but output is something "@yahoo.comATRICIAALISHA" , i tried 1 day but unable to know where is the problem. as you can see firstname and lastname variable are printed correctly then why email is not printed correctly ?

Comment: Seems like you have not post updated Code. But need to clean project then re try

Comment: There is probably an `'\r'` character at the end of `lastname`.  Try outputting `lastname.length()` and see if it's 7 instead of 6.

Comment: on your screen shot email is .. not appearing . ? need to update correct snapshot related to uploaded code

Comment: ok, so my code is correct ? i have cleaned it already.

Comment: code and screenshot is up to date,

Comment: Your code is far from good - but at least it should not produce the output you provided.

Comment: After cleaning  Run the java class and see   what should appear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output is consistent with `lastname` being `"ALISHA\r"`.  What happens is that when you print it (depending on your OS), the `\r` character causes the cursor to go back to the beginning of the line.  This has no effect on the appearance of the output in the cases where you print `"last name is"` or `"full name is"`, since the cursor will just go to the next line anyway.  But it causes `email` to be `"PATRICIAALISHA\r@yahoo.com"`, which means that after it outputs `email is PATRICIAALISHA`, the cursor goes back to the beginning of the line and overwrites what's already there with `@yahoo.com`, which is just enough to overwrite the text up through the P.

Comment: Thanks A Lot, you are really Genius. =D

Comment: No, just been doing this long enough to run into problems like this many times.